# How to create user and post in WordPress REMOTELY from another server

Tags: wordpress

I have a site ABC.COM with WordPress installed and another site DEF.COM which is purely done by hardcoding. And both of the sites are located in two different servers.

What I wanna do sounds simple but I have no idea how to start. **I want to create a user and a post remotely and automatically in ABC.COM when a user and a post is created in DEF.COM.**

Comment: Users are just entries in a database table. Just install PHPMyAdmin and examine the database structure. The layout isn't hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess around with the wordpress api/source you can try database replication.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication

Comment: Is there a wordpress-built-in way to do this? Can WordPress XML-PRC do this?